# multiple sites on heroku: suggestions on database management?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I am developing a site using rails and deploying it to heroku.  It will eventually have quite a lot of data, for now the beta/demo has just under 300k rows which is over the limit for the free development level on heroku.

I am purchasing the basic level for the production deployment of the site but we have a second deployment we are using to test deployments as we develop features etc.  This data should be distinct from the production data so users can freely mess with it and it doesn't pollute the production/beta users.

We have a third deployment that our marketing people want to use as a demo that should also be a distinct set up of data.

does anyone have any suggestions for how to manage this?  We'd rather not have to pay for 3 databases if we can avoid it - the staging and demo sites aren't going to be public facing or revenue generating.  they also won't see much traffic at all (VERY little).  I like having the site on heroku because we want to make sure our deployments are not having heroku specific problems before we go production with them...

thanks for your consideration.

Max

Comment: Look at using Postgres' schema features, too. Perfect for this use-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think about it, your staging environment doesn't have to have 300K+ rows of data. Just some seed data and you should be good to go. Therefore, there shouldn't be a need to purchase the basic tier - the dev tier should be more than enough.

Comment: that's what I'm doing right now and I can work with it.  it would be nice to not have to manage it as a seperate piece but I guess that's what I'll have to keep doing.  thanks for the feedback.